# Connections to the SharePoint server are currently disabled because the project is in Offline mode

Tags: sharepoint

[Project got offline. Please let me know the proper reasons and root cause for this problem and how to set these property in to the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uP2ZT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the code, but to the project settings in Visual Studio.

Check that you have configured a valid Site URL and the Server Connection is set to online.

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgohh.png) how it should look like.